# Codeigniter - count all on the table not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

could ya'll help me on this one please. I'm trying to count how many are there in my table as it doesn't show up the result on my view.

**Controller**

```
  public function enrollment_summary()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Enrollment Summary';
    $this->load->model('report_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->report_model->get_students();
    $this->load->view('report_enrollment_summary', $data);
  }
```

**Model**

```
 <?php
class report_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }
  public function get_students()
  {
    $query = $this->db->count_all('students');
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<body>
  <h1>Enrollment Summary</h1>
  <?php echo $query; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get_students() is not returning anything?

So you need to add in a return.

Your current method...

```
  public function get_students()
  {
    $query = $this->db->count_all('students');
  }
```

becomes

```
  public function get_students()
  {
    $query = $this->db->count_all('students');
    return $query;
  }
```

OR

```
  public function get_students()
  {
    return $this->db->count_all('students');
  }
```